# DetailsView Word-Wrap issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, detailsview

I Have an [DetailsView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w1w7t4.aspx) with the property `wrap=true`. However I want the detailsview to word-wrap, **not** break words. How can I change these properties inside of the detailsview?

[Here is an example of it happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDHZq.png).

Details View Snippet:

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
  DataKeyNames="AccidentId" DataSourceID="srcDetails" DefaultMode="Edit" 
  Height="50px" Width="919px" onitemupdated="DetailsView1_ItemUpdated" 
  onitemupdating="DetailsView1_ItemUpdating" style="margin-right: 0px">
   <Fields>
    <EditItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox10" runat="server" Height="60px" 
         Text='<%# Bind("ActionInvolved") %>' TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500px">   </asp:TextBox>
     </EditItemTemplate>
   </Fields>
 </asp:DetailsView>
```

EDIT: I have figured out that this issue only happens when I set the width of my detailsview to 100% and set static width's to my textfield. Any idea of how to set these properties without it happening?

Comment: Can you post a snippet of the DetailsView markup please?

Comment: Sure thing. This is just one of my template fields. Obviously theres more. But this is the field causing me issues.

Comment: I have tried to recreate this issue but cannot. I suspect it may be a CSS issue; can you post any CSS being applied to the text box please?

Comment: No CSS on the textbox :| thats why im so confused as well.

Comment: are you sure there's no CSS being applied? What browser is it? I ask because it's a multi-line text box in your image but there's no scrollbar - see the comment box on SO for example!

Comment: IE9 and its not a textbox its a label. :| although in the edit view (when it turns into a multiline textbox) it does the same thing as well...